# Can ibid. be used under the Harvard referencing style?

Tags: citations, citation-style

In other words, **not** the other styles (e.g. APA, Chicago, Oxford) that uses the author-date format but the plain (Australian?) Harvard style.

Comment: What does "used" mean? Where precisely? What is "Harvard style"? "APA/Chicago/Oxford" styles? I've written dozens of papers and never heard of these terms.

Comment: @Dilworth Those are all well known, writing style guidelines.

Comment: Certainly, it is not THAT well known... Indeed, these are *not* even writing styles, but **referencing** styles!

Comment: @Dilworth Please don't be pedantic: the question is quite clearly tagged with "citation-style".  Likewise, please remember that [academia varies more than you may think](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1212/22733).

Comment: @jakebeal, as I said, I've written dozens of papers and have never heard of these styles (perhaps only extremely vaguely I recall the term "Harvard style"), so I was not being pedantic at all, I *truly* think many readers will not have a clue what the question is about!

Comment: @jakebeal, please also note that your link supports my complaint: since academia varies a lot, what is evident to the OP is far from obvious for most readers.

Comment: @Dilworth Playing devil's advocate, but someone who has no idea what "Harvard style" is wouldn't be able to answer the question or profit from its answers anyway... I don't go to numerical analysis questions on mathoverflow and complain I don't know the words that are used...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, Please note that I have already explained that as someone who published many papers, I should be more qualified on average than most users here to answer such questions, and still I have barely heard of these concepts. A reasonable question should explain the concepts it uses to the reader. Also, these questions are here for reference, not just for the use of the OP, making your first argument dubious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the examples at [the University of the West of England](http://ro.uwe.ac.uk/RenderPages/RenderLearningObject.aspx?Context=6&Area=1&Room=2&Constellation=22&LearningObject=91):

> Generally ibid. and op.cit. tend to be used more in the body text for the Harvard system, and more in the reference list for the numeric system, as you can see.

They also note:

> There is no single authority that defines the 'Harvard' referencing style. Please seek guidance on the preferred scheme of referencing from your home institution or the journal in which your study will appear.

So I'm going to say yes, there is no reason as to why you couldn't use *ibid* with the Harvard citation style.